# Rails mysql2 gem error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql2

I've installed mysql in my system using homebrew.

Inside rails app, i changed my adapter from `"sqlite3"` to `"mysql2"` and included `mysql2` in my gemfile and version 0.5.1 got installed.

Rails version is 3.2.1.

I'm getting this error while doing `rake db:create`.

```
"Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (can't activate mysql2 (~> 0.3.10), already activated mysql2-0.5.1. Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile.)"
```

Comment: Did you run `bundle install` on your current _Gemfile_?

Comment: Yes , i did bundle install and mysql2  0.5.1 got installed. After that , im getting the above mentioned error.